# how to stop consuming messages from kafka when error occurred and restart consuming again after some time in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

This is the first time i am using Kafka. i have a spring boot application and i am consuming messages from kafka topics and storing messages in DB. I have a requirement to handle DB fail over, if DB is down that message should not be committed and suspend consuming messages for some time and after some time listener can start consuming messages again. what is the better approach to do this.

```
 i am using spring-kafka:2.2.8.RELEASE which is internally using kafka 2.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Configure a `ContainerStoppingErrorHandler` and throw an exception from your listener.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.13.RELEASE/reference/html/#container-stopping-error-handlers

You can restart the container later when you have detected that your DB is back online.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.13.RELEASE/reference/html/#kafkalistener-lifecycle

**EDIT**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So62125817Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So62125817Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    TaskScheduler scheduler() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so62125817").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

}

@Component
class Listener {

    private final TaskScheduler scheduler;

    private final KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

    public Listener(TaskScheduler scheduler, KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry,
            AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?, ?> factory) {

        this.scheduler = scheduler;
        this.registry = registry;
        factory.setErrorHandler(new ContainerStoppingErrorHandler());
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so62125817.id", topics = "so62125817")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        // run this code if you want to stop the container and restart it in 60 seconds
        this.scheduler.schedule(() -> {
            this.registry.getListenerContainer("so62125817.id").start();
        }, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 60_000));
        throw new RuntimeException("test restart");
    }

}
```

Comment: @Gery Russell, can you please help me to know from where i can call Start() method after a minute  when my handle() method of ContainerStoppingErrorHandler() is executed and consumer stopped. can you please help me with small piece of code.

Comment: I added an example to my answere.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches which I can think of doing this:

**First Approach:** Let the auto-commit option for consuming messages be true. The configuration for this is `enable.auto.commit`. By default, this would be true, so you do not need to change anything. Whenever your DB operation fails, you can put the messages on a different topic say a topic named `failed_events`. When you do this, you can have the same application (Which populates the DB) running say once at a daily level to consume the message from `failed_events` topic and populate the DB again. This way you can keep track of how many times the DB write gets failed. One small thing to note is what if during this run also the DB is down, then what do you do. You can decide what to do in this case. Probably discard the message if it is Ok to do so, or do a certain number of retries.

**Second approach:** If it is very deterministic to know that for how long the DB would be down. And if the time period is very small, then it is better to do a sleep operation in the case of DB write failure. Say the application sleeps for 10 minutes before it retries again. You will not have to create a separate topic in this case.

The **advantage** of this approach is that you don't have to run a separate instance of the same application to fetch from a different topic. You could do all of them in one single application. Maintaining this becomes relatively easier.

The **disadvantage** of this approach is that if the DB is down for a very long period, say 1 day, Then you will end up losing the message.